# Why does the debugger step through a destructor in a for-in loop?

Tags: delphi, debugging, for-loop, empty-list

In Delphi XE7 (I use RAD Studio), I try to debug a code inside a package. I'm in trouble with a strange situation that I cannot explain. For example, I have a function similar to the one below (**NOTE** I know, this function does nothing intelligent, please don't correct it because I don't use it in the real world. It's just a dummy function to illustrate the issue I face.)

```pascal
procedure TMyClass.DemoFunc();
var
    pTest:     TObjectList<TObject>;
    pProperty: TObject;
begin
    pTest := TObjectList<TObject>.Create;

    for pProperty in pTest do
        pProperty.ToString;

    pTest.Free;
end;
```

When I debug the above code, I notice that the debugger enters on the line

```pascal
pProperty.ToString;
```

If I try to trace into the above line, I jump to

```pascal
destructor TObject.Destroy;
```

But from my point of view it's completely illogical, because pTest is clearly empty, and so the above line should never be called.

Somebody can explain to me this strange behavior?

**NOTE** The code I try to debug is inside a Delphi package, but the function is called from a c++ project.

Regards

Comment: It bugs me that Emba decided to use heap allocated enumerators for their basic collections. It's as if the developers don't understand the cost implications of the heap.

Comment: So this may be a valid reason to use a for-to loop instead?

Comment: Mostly it doesn't matter. But if you are doing serious multi-threading code on huge machines then memory manager contention can be an issue.

Comment: Maybe in this simple case, to avoid the heap allocation.  Probably doesn't really matter unless your working in a much more complex code, multi-threads and large memory consumption

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The TObject being destroyed is the Enumerator that was created implicitly by the compiler for the For-In loop.  It is not the "pProperty".  If you bring up an Evaluator when the debugger is stopped at the begin of TObject.Destroy and enter "self.classname" you will see that it's a "TList<System.TObject>.TEnumerator".